# This operation is not permitted; Adobe LiveCycle Designer

Tags: pdf, adobe, designer, acrobat, livecycle

I'm using Adobe Acrobat 8 Professional, I have created a form using LiveCycle Designer (from a PDF ) that contains only text fields, radio buttons and check boxes. When the form is saved, it can be opened without trouble in both Reader and Professional. However, when I select 'Enable User Rights in Adobe Reader' with Acrobat, save, close and re-open, the file opens (in Professional and Reader) with the message 'This operation is not permitted'. After two click-throughs the error box disappears, but it's a bit unprofessional and I can't get it to go away.

Answer (score 0):

If I undertstanded well,  you have created the form in designer by importing a pre existent pdf.
I'm working with a very complex pdf and I also tried to import it in designer, but the result was really dirt and I get a lot of errors.
So I builded a new form from scratch and it worked perfeclty.
Maybe is the same for you.